# Changing the collating sequence for an index

Tags: indexing, punctuation

How do I change the collating sequence for indexes so that, say, "in-range" after "India"?  That is, I want things alphabetized as if the punctuation marks were not there.  This applies to dashes, periods, commas, etc.

Comment: `\index{inrange@in-range}`

Comment: Are you using `makeindex` or `xindy`? (`xindy` has the `ignore-hypen.xdy` module.)

Comment: Yes, but I want it to be general so that ALL punctuation is ignored, including periods, spaces, commas, etc., in all entries.

Comment: `xindy` also has `ignore-punctuation.xdy`.

Comment: I'd prefer to do this in makeindex rather than add a new package in the days before the book goes into production!  Any way?